# Object has width and height property in console, but doesn't have those properties after JSON.stringify();

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, image, width

I have an Object A with list of urls for images. I created object B after modified properties from A. Then I tried to add width and height properties for B object, but after I stringify it, the width and height disappears. However, they are there in console.log(B). Can anyone tell me what is going on?

```
var B = {
  "seattle": {
    url: "http://dummyimage.com/800x600/4d494d/686a82.gif&text=placeholder+image"
  }
}
for (var prop in B) {
    getImgProperties(B[prop]);
}


function getImgProperties(eachCityIn_B) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = eachCityIn_B.url;

    img.onload = function() {
        eachCityIn_B.width =  img.width;
        eachCityIn_B.height = img.height;
    };
}

console.log(B); //width and height are defind
console.log(JSON.stringify(B)); // No width and height properties!???
```

Here an example on codepen http://codepen.io/Samjin/pen/VKOoNJ?editors=0010
If you look at browser console, it shows Seattle object with height and width properties, but stringified value doesn't have them. How to I add the height and width value to B object?

Comment: How are the two objects (`eachCityIn_B` and `B`) related?

Comment: eachCityIn_B is same as B[prop], i'll add an example soon

Comment: what is `B`? Please show exactly how it is created

Comment: Did the `onload` already happen when you call `stringify`? (console.log output may be delayed from when you call it, and include later updates to `B`).

Comment: `onload` will occur *after* the log statements. An object in the console is not a snapshot, any updates to properties after it is logged will be reflected. Stringify will however produce a snapshot

Comment: Sorry, I am still bit confusing here. What is the issue and how can I add height and width to B object?

Comment: You are adding...move your log statements inside `onload`

Comment: Thanks guys, if you make an answer, I'll vote it. :)